# Share Internet between two Macbook Pros (thunderbolt)

Tags: vpn

**WHAT I WANT TO ACHIEVE**

I have two Macbook Pros (Mojave 10.14.6) with me in a country different than US. A and B. What I need and requirements:

I want computer B to be connected from a US IP address at all times.
I cannot install a VPN in B, but I can install anything in computer A, including a VPN.
WHAT I THOUGHT IT COULD BE A SOLUTION AND WHAT I TRIED

I thought I could make computer B to connect to the Internet through computer A's (through A's VPN) Internet connection so that that if I check computer B's IP address shows the US IP address.

I've been able to share the internet connection from A to B with Thunderbolt 3 cable. However, when I check https://www.whatismyip.com/ within B it shows still the IP as if I was connected to the router in the local region and not the US location.

How can achieve this? Please let me know if you need any clarification.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: A is the only one getting an external IP.  B is just sharing the same connection with A, it doesn't get it's own external IP address.

Comment: Actually it does. When I check the ip address both are different @fsb

Comment: Can you [edit] your question to include the external IP address of both computers?